# Rails throughput spike reported as middleware/Rack/ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, newrelic

I'm getting occasional throughput spikes in my `Rails 5` app hosted on `Heroku`. The spikes are reported in `New Relic` with the following transaction name: `middleware/Rack/ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call`. The spikes result in `~200rmp` of those transactions and render the application unresponsive. Restart of the Heroku dyno solves the problem.

What might be causing this behavior? Where should I look?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351527/actiondispatchroutingroutesetcall-rails-4-1-really-slow

Answer (score 0):

On our system we found that `Middleware/Rack/ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet` was mapping to a 404s in NewRelic